# Absolute (external) URLs with Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm unable to get Html.ActionLink to produce absolute urls.

```
Html.ActionLink(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Name").ToString(), DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Path").ToString())
```

This pulls the data from my model correctly, but appends the path to the end of the current page, producing URLs like "http://localhost:24590/www.google.com"

How can I get this to work how I want it to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an absolute URL starting with i.e. `http://`.

```
<a href="www.google.com"></a>
```

would have the same result, because it's a relative url.

Comment: not sure how this answers the question.  I am running into the same issue and not sure how to generate a url with an absolute path.  For example, I've attempted to do something like Html.ActionLink("test link", "http://www.google.com") and it generates what Skrealin is complaining about.  Then, I tried <a href="http://www.google.com">test link</a> and it yielded the same result.  So, how can this be done?

Comment: As i wrote in the answer, use an absolute URL. The ActionLink helper tries to provide a URL for your website, so if you give a relative path, he has to think it's part of your page. You have to explicitly set an absolute URL and this is done by having i.e. `http://` in front. You should use `Html.ActionLink("test link", "http://google.com")`.

Comment: This is incorrect.Html.ActionLink() only generates paths relative to the current project, so that would tack on "google.com" to the end of the current host/URI path.

Answer (score 17):

This works for me:

```
<a href="http://@Model.URL">
    Click Here
</a>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. When attempting to link to an EXTERNAL resource (i.e., a different website or file not in your project), there is no need for the @Html.ActionLink helper, which is only for generating RELATIVE links to routes in your project.